# tune() function e1071 / libsvm -error with rpart

Tags: r, rpart

I am trying to tune `rpart`. I have already split my data into a training and cv set. The `tune.rpart` convenience function doesn't seem to have a a way to specify a cv set. so I am using the regular `tune()` function.

I have 595 potential variables in my dataset, so I don't want to specify using a formula. I get the following error when I do this

```
Error in tune(rpart, train.x = trainset[, -1], train.y = trainset[, 1],  : 
Dependent variable has wrong type!
In addition: Warning message:
In if (y) ans$y <- Y :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Code:

```
load('train.dat')
load('cv.dat')
trainset$class<-factor(trainset$class)
cvset$class<-factor(cvset$class)

rpart.tune<-tune(rpart,train.x= trainset[,-1], train.y=trainset[,1],
           validation.x=cvset[,-1], validation.y=cvset[,1],
             ranges = list(
               cp = c(0.002,0.005,0.01,0.015,0.02,0.03)),
           tunecontrol = tune.control(sampling = "fix"))
```

Data is available at:
https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B2_rKFnvrjMAM3FGbnFvZm5laUk/edit

Comment: Your example is not reproducible as your data is not avaiable.

Comment: I changed the settings. it should be available now. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the prediction output of the classifier you are using. `tune()` expects (for classification) receive one of the following:

```
(is.logical(true.y) || is.factor(true.y)) && (is.logical(pred) || is.factor(pred) || is.character(pred))
```

The prediction with `rpart`, for example, produces a matrix as output. You can try `svm`that handles that right or try to give just two classes.